# Android Loader returning incorrect item

Tags: android

I am trying to learn about Loaders and have what is a fairly standard setup - a list drawn from a database, when item is selected the detail is retrieved and displayed. It works well on the first click, but always returns the same data regardless of which list item is clicked after that. I stepped through the code and determined that everything is working, but the real data is ignored because the original loader is reused.  Here is a bit of the code:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Cursor cursor  = (Cursor)this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String mId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putString(ID, mId);
    LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
    LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    lm.initLoader(1, args, new NewsLoaderCallbacks());

}
// News item callbacks
private class NewsLoaderCallbacks implements LoaderCallbacks<SingleNewsItem> {
    @Override
    public Loader<SingleNewsItem> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Log.i("DEBUG", "In oncreateloader");
        return new SingleNewsItemLoader(getActivity(), args.getString(ID));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<SingleNewsItem> itemLoader,
            SingleNewsItem item) {
        // display the item here
        Log.i("DEBUG", "In onloadfinished");
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleNewsItemActivity.class);
        //i.putExtra(ID, item.getId());
        i.putExtra("ID", item);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<SingleNewsItem> arg0) {
        // nothing
    }

 public class SingleNewsItemLoader extends DataLoader<SingleNewsItem> {

String mNewsItemId;

public SingleNewsItemLoader(Context context, String id) {
    super(context);
    mNewsItemId = id;
}

@Override
public SingleNewsItem loadInBackground() {

    return NewsManager.get(getContext()).getOneItem(mNewsItemId);
}

 }
```

So onCreateLoader sets the id property in SingleNewsItemLoader and the onLoadFinished recieves back the detailed item.  But it seems when a different item is clicked on the list, onCreate does not update the id property.  Here is the debug log:

```
 09-30 16:04:25.997: V/LoaderManager(2599): initLoader in LoaderManager{40d16138 in  GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}: args=Bundle[{id=4 charged in mass shooting at park: 'God  took care of them' - Chicago Tribune}]
 09-30 16:04:25.997: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Starting: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:26.006: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Created new loader LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:26.086: V/LoaderManager(2599): onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 :   SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:26.097: V/LoaderManager(2599):   onLoadFinished in SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8 id=1}: SingleNewsItem{40e7bd88}
 09-30 16:04:33.376: V/LoaderManager(2599): Stopping in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}
 09-30 16:04:33.376: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Stopping: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:33.396: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Stopping: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:04:35.436: V/LoaderManager(2599): Starting in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}
 09-30 16:04:35.436: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Starting: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:35.446: V/LoaderManager(2599): onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:35.446: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Starting: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:04:35.446: V/LoaderManager(2599): onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 :  NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:04:39.136: V/LoaderManager(2599): initLoader in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}: args=Bundle[{id=Conservatives resolute on Obamacare, but Sen. Coburn says strategy won't work - Washington Post}]
 09-30 16:04:39.136: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:39.196: V/LoaderManager(2599):   onLoadFinished in SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8 id=1}: SingleNewsItem{40e7bd88}
 09-30 16:04:45.795: V/LoaderManager(2599): Stopping in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}
 09-30 16:04:45.795: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Stopping: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : S   ingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:45.805: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Stopping: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:04:46.235: V/LoaderManager(2599): Starting in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}
 09-30 16:04:46.235: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Starting: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:46.255: V/LoaderManager(2599): onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:04:46.255: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Starting: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:04:46.296: V/LoaderManager(2599): onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:06:23.906: V/LoaderManager(2599): initLoader in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}: args=Bundle[{id=Obama directs Kerry to pursue talks with Iran over nuclear weapons deal - Fox News}]
 09-30 16:06:23.906: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Re-using existing loader LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:06:23.936: V/LoaderManager(2599):   onLoadFinished in SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8 id=1}: SingleNewsItem{40e7bd88}
 09-30 16:06:29.066: V/LoaderManager(2599): Stopping in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}
 09-30 16:06:29.066: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Stopping: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:06:29.066: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Stopping: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:06:34.316: V/LoaderManager(2599): Starting in LoaderManager{40d16138 in GoogleNewsMainActivity{40ced590}}
 09-30 16:06:34.316: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Starting: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
 09-30 16:06:34.316: V/LoaderManager(2599): onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{40e78278 #1 : SingleNewsItemLoader{40e788f8}}
  09-30 16:06:34.316: V/LoaderManager(2599):   Starting: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
 09-30 16:06:34.325: V/LoaderManager(2599): onLoadComplete: LoaderInfo{40d16c78 #0 : NewsListCursorLoader{40d17aa8}}
```

If you scroll the log all the way to the left you can see that the ID has changed (they are headlines), but if you stop in the debugger and look at the item object returned, it is always the first one.  So the property in SingleNewsItemLoader never changes.

What am I missing here?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [LoaderManager.initLoader()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29):

> Ensures a loader is initialized and active. If the loader doesn't already exist, one is created and (if the activity/fragment is currently started) starts the loader. **Otherwise the last created loader is re-used.**

Use `restartLoader` to restart the loader with new arguments.

Comment: In general, you can use restartLoader _instead of_ initLoader if you don't do anything special the first time content is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Like ianhanniballake said, you need to either use `LoaderManager.restartLoader()` or `LoaderManager.distroyLoader()` and then use `LoaderManager.initLoader()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the id you are passing to `initLoader()` right now it is a constant 1, try :

```
lm.initLoader(position, args, new NewsLoaderCallbacks());
```

Comment: The one is a constant that simply identifies the loader so it can be distinguished from others. The first answer above solved the problem. Changing to restartLoader causes the Create method to be called every time and that solves the problem.  thanks.